# Unable to call Dispose?

Tags: .net, c#-2.0

This one has confused me a little... Attempting to dispose of an XmlReader

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath);
reader.Dispose();
```

Provides the following error:

> 'System.Xml.XmlReader.Dispose(bool)' is inaccessible due to its
>   protection level

however the following is fine:

```
using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
{
}
```

When I look at the definition in Reflector I can't understand why I can't call Dispose

[image: XmlReader]

Implementation of Dispose:

[image: Dispose]

Can anyone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: You are looking at the disassembly of .NET 4's `XmlReader`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem is that `XmlReader` uses *explicit interface implementation* to [implement `IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355649.aspx). So you *can* write:

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath);
((IDisposable)reader).Dispose();
```

However, I'd strongly suggest using a `using` statement anyway. It should be *very* rare that you call `Dispose` explicitly, other than within another `Dispose` implementation.

EDIT: As noted, this is "fixed" in .NET 4.5, in that it exposes a [public parameterless `Dispose` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc310545.aspx) as of .NET 4.5 as well as the explicit interface implementation. So presumably you're compiling against .NET 4.0 or earlier (perhaps .NET 2.0 given your tags) but using Reflector against .NET 4.5?

Comment: This seems to be 'fixed' in .NET 4. I wonder what the original intention was with the explicit implementation?

Comment: @leppie: Not sure, but I think it's true of a few classes - this isn't the first time I've seen it.

Comment: `System.Xml` is not exactly know for it's good style ;p IIRC several `new` members etc in .NET 1.x (not sure about newer ones).

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks for the good answer. Yeah, I'm compiling against .NET 2.0 (I'll update my tags) and I imagine much of the confusion came from Reflector not showing the assembly I thought it was... I thought I'd switched to .NET 2.0 but obviously not.

Comment: Looks to me like this was 'fixed'/changed in .NET 4.5, not .NET 4 as suggested above. It's confusing because the 4.5 assemblies have a 4.0.x version number.

Comment: @locster: It's not that that confused me - it's that you can select .NET 4 as the framework version, at which point it shows that it's available for PCLs. All very odd. Will update the answer though.

Answer (score -2):

```
using(XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath))
{
   foo(reader);
}
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath);
try 
{
   code(reader);
} 
finally
{
   if(reader != null)
     ((IDisposable)reader).Dispose();
}
```

The most likely thing is that you haven't posted all of your code - perhaps someone else is calling Dispose() on your object as well, causing an exception in the second call to Dispose()?

Comment: No, it's not exactly equivalent to that. It handles nullity, and it implicitly casts to `IDisposable` if required due to explicit interface implementation - which is the case here.

Comment: Pre-.NET 4.0, XmlReader implements IDisposable explicitly.  Your `reader.Dispose()` should be `((IDisposable)reader).Dispose()`

Comment: ''The most likely thing is that you haven't posted all of your code'' If you'd tried it, those two lines he posted were enough to show the problem.

Comment: As weston said... The code I posted is exactly that, it's a build error not a runtime error.