# .Net 4.0 System.Xml.dll different versions?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, system.xml

I was trying to use the Dispose method of the `XmlReader` but it seemed it wasn't available. After looking [around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9582320/unable-to-call-dispose) on the internet, I found out that in .Net 2.0 the `IDisposable.Dispose` method was implemented explicitly, but that this was "corrected" in .Net 4.0. Indeed, when I checked the method with .Net Reflector it was exposed publicly.

But although my project used .Net 4.0 as target framework, I still could not call the Dispose method without explicit casting the XmlReader to IDisposable.

Then I noticed that .Net Reflector decompiled `C:\Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Xml.dll` while my project used `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Xml.dll` as reference. I decompiled the latter and indeed, the `Dispose` method is still implemented explicitly in that one.

Why are there 2 different versions of the same dll for the same version of the framework ?

Can my Visual Studio 2010 be configured to use `C:\Windows\Microsoft.net\Framework\v4.0.30319\` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0` when referencing the framework ?

P.S. I did not yet install the .Net 4.5 framework.